# How to select columns in a loop with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have this query. DDIFF is just a difference of two Date columns in the table:

```
SELECT 
    DDIFF,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Franchise' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Franchise Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Own' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Own Count]
FROM
    dbo.joined
GROUP BY
    DDIFF, Franchise
ORDER BY
    DDIFF
```

And this is a fragment of the output:

```
DDIFF   Franchise Count Own Count
----------------------------------
NULL    0               1
-31     0               3
-28     0               13
-20     2               0
-16     1               0
-13     0               2
...
```

I'm getting sales data made for Franchises or 'Own' shops.

But I want to get these counts divided to months, so I need to make some kind of loop to get this two column for every month of the year (meaning 12x2 columns)

To have something like this:

```
DDIFF   [2019.01 Franchise] [2019.01 Own] [2019.02 Franchise] [2019.02 Own] ...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
NULL    0                   1             0                   1
-31     0                   0             2                   1
-28     0                   10            0                   3
-20     1                   0             1                   0
-16     1                   0             0                   0
-13     0                   1             0                   1
...
```

I guess I need to creat some kind of loop and add an `AND dateColumn = year.month` condition at the `CASE WHEN` ... to build the actual column for that month, or even an embedded loop to cover multiple years.

Is there a syntax which lets me create columns like this?

Comment: Once you add or expose your dateColumn, this would be a simple pivot or conditional aggregation,

Comment: you do not need a loop.  Explore the pivot operator.  You'll also want to leverage a  DATE column rather than just using the DDIFF.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti What do you mean under exposing my dateColumn?

Comment: @MattSom in your query and sample data I see no dates to build off of.  I suspect DDIFF has something to do with DateDiff, but it unclear

Comment: loops don't exist in SQL so that won't be the solution.  Can you explain what you want without talking about something that does not exist?

Comment: @Hogan It does exist in T-SQL, but that was just an idea I was thinking about as a possible solution. I don't get what is unclear to you. I have many date columns in my table and I just want to create the same results only with more columns dividing the data for every month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT 
    DDIFF,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Franchise' and month(datefiled) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.1 Franchise Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Own' and month(datefiled) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.1 Own Count],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Franchise' and month(datefiled) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.2 Franchise Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Own' and month(datefiled) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.2 Own Count],

    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Franchise' and month(datefiled) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.3 Franchise Count],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Franchise = 'Own' and month(datefiled) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [2019.3 Own Count],

-- etc

FROM  dbo.joined
GROUP BY DDIFF
ORDER BY DDIFF
```

Comment: Yes, exactly! I know my question looks messy, but I just have a real hard time to explain it, given I'm also a beginner with SQL Server. But yes this is what I want, only that I have to cover 3 years, meaning 3x24 columns. And what if I want the previous 10 years instead? So I'm looking for something more dynamic solution.

Comment: @MattSom This is what was meant by pivot or conditional aggregation.   The missing element was the NAME of the date column.  I find it odd that you took the time to protest the down vote (and later delete), yet made no effort to address the missing element.   Furthermore, the phrase "I don't get what is unclear to you." should be a que to ask yourself "What am I not communicating?"     +1 Hogan

Comment: @JohnCappelletti
Yes, I'm sorry for that. My table is just simply huge and I just can't get an angle how to present my question the best way. But getting a downvote fore that just creates frustration instead of suggestions. I've created a new, more verbose question asking for help with the pivot solution itself, as this question is truly a mess and now I have somewhat clearer picture about what information I should share and what to omit. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56793794/6560773

Comment: @MattSom -- pivot solution won't help, you have to know all the dimensions for that at the start.  You probably want a dynamic SQL solution

Comment: @MattSom -- if you want performance you could also use an XML solution -- then just mark up the result set -- if your looking for a web based result that is probably the best and fastest.